# Socket.io NodeJS chat : Why do messages emit multiple times?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, callback, socket.io

I am trying to create a nodeJS/Socket.io chat app. But whenever I send a message it emits multiple time s for some reason. 
Client Side:

```
var socket = io.connect();
var $users = $('#users');
var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
var $messageBox = $('#message');
var $chat = $('#chat');

socket.emit('new user', "{{user.username}}", function(data){
    if(data) {
        console.log("Connected");
    }

});

socket.on('usernames', function(data){
    var html = '';
    for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        html += data[i] + '<br/>'
    }
    $users.html(html);
});

$messageForm.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('send message', $messageBox.val(), function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $chat.append('<span class="error">' + "asdfasdfaf" + "</span><br/>");
});
    $messageBox.val('');
});

socket.on('load old msgs', function(docs){
    for(var i=docs.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        displayMsg(docs[i]);
    }
});

socket.on('new message', function(data){
     displayMsg(data);
});

function displayMsg(data){
    $chat.append(
        '<span class="msg"><b>' + 
        data.nick + ': </b>' + data.msg + "</span><br/>");
}

socket.on('whisper', function(data){
    $chat.append(
        '<span class="whisper"><b>' + 
        data.nick + ': </b>' + data.msg + "</span><br/>");
});
```

And here is the server side code (this code is inside an app.get() request):

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    var query = Chat.find({});
    query.sort('-created').limit(8).exec(function(err, docs){
    if(err) throw err;
    // socket.emit('load old msgs', docs);
});

socket.on('new user', function(data, callback){
    socket.nickname = req.user.username;
    users[socket.nickname] = socket;
});



socket.on('send message', function(data, callback){
    var msg = data.trim();
    console.log('after trimming message is: ' + msg);
    var name = req.params.posteruname;

    if(name in users){
        users[name].emit('whisper', {msg: msg, nick: socket.nickname});
        console.log('message sent is: ' + msg);
        console.log('Whisper!');
    } else{
        callback('Error!  Enter a valid user.');
    }


});

socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
    delete users[req.user.username];
    updateNicknames();
});
```

So basically the problem is that every time the, 'send message' method is triggered the message is sent out multiple times(the amount of times the page is refreshed) - > I make sure that a new socket is not created when a page is refreshed by the same user, to avoid multiple messages. But multiple messages are still sent. I have been stuck here for a while. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You said 'this code is inside an app.get() request'. It means each time a client connects to your server, io.sockets.on is triggered again. So this should be out of the scope of your route. If you post complete server code then I may be able to help further

Comment: Yes, that was causing the problem. I moved the code outside the get request and it doesn't emit multiple times anymore! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The listener on  your server side code should not act unless it recieves an event, hence the problem probably is at client side. It is triggers server message listener more then once..
try any other event like .click(function(){}) or on('click',function(){}) of jquery..